# Powershell: copying profiles from one location to another

Tags: powershell

trying to iterate over a profiles folder to copy their desktop a new location, but cant piece together the iteration properly.

```
get-childitem -path c:\users\*\desktop\ `
| ForEach-Object { Copy-Item $_ -Force -Destination D:\Users\*\ }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So something like this then?

```
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\users | ForEach-Object{
    Copy-Item "$($_.FullName)\Desktop" -Force -Destination "D:\Users\$($_.Name)\Desktop"
}
```

Let it figure out what the user names are in the folder (Might have to omit some users like Administrator). Then using the folder names collected (Represented by `$_.Name` inside the loop) we can use that to address the source desktop and destination desktop. Warning that this does not do any error checking for path validation. Something like that would be very prone to error since you cannot guarantee that a folder will exist in the target.

Could address that with something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\users -Exclude "public","administrator" | ForEach-Object{
    $sourceDesktop = "$($_.FullName)\Desktop"
    $targetDesktop = "D:\Users\$($_.Name)\Desktop"


    If(((Test-Path $sourceDesktop,$targetDesktop) -eq $false).Count -gt 0){
        Copy-Item $sourceDesktop -Destination $targetDesktop -Force
    }
}
```

`(((Test-Path $sourceDesktop,$targetDesktop) -eq $false).Count -gt 0)` breaks down like this

1. `Test-Path` will be returning an array of `True``False` for all folders provided.
2. If any of the tests return false at least one of the folders does not exist so we should not attempt the transfer.

Also has an exclusion section that you could remove if you chose to.

Comment: Nice Matt, appreciate the help!